# Delete the first x character in a file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I writting a program. But I have a problem.

I want to delete the first x character from a file.

```
msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    if len(msg) < 2:
      print "Exit"
      break
    try:
      myfile = open('logs/demo.txt','a')
      msg = msg.replace('\n','')
      msg = msg.replace(' ','')
      myfile.write(msg)
      myfile.flush()
      myfile.close() 
    except IOError:
      print "write error"
    finally:
      myfile.close()
    try:

      myfile.close()
      myfile=open("logs/demo.txt","r+")
      firstdata=myfile.read()  
      firstdata.replace('\n','')
      firstdata.replace(' ','')

      son = firstdata.rfind("#")
      firstdata = firstdata[:son]
      print firstdata
      #os.remove("logs/demo.txt")
      myfile.close()
      os.remove("logs/demo.txt")

      myfile = open('logs/demo.txt','a')
      firstdata = firstdata.replace('\n','')
      firstdata = firstdata.replace(' ','')
      myfile.write(firstdata[son:])
      myfile.flush()
      myfile.close() 

    except IOError:
      print "read error"
    finally:
      myfile.close()
```

This code is too long and I open the file 3 times.

I want:

Before deleting:

```
    In file : "asdfghjkl#mnbvc#qwerty#poiuyt"
```

After deleting:

```
    In file : "poiuyt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the first x characters from a file where x is an integer (in this example 23), then

```
with open("logs/demo-out.txt","w") as output:
    with open("logs/demo.txt","r") as input:
        output.write(input.read()[23:])
```

Updating a textfile in place (except for adding stuff at the end) requires either (1) that you read the data into memory, close the file, reopen it, and overwrite the original file with the modified data; or (2) that you write out a fresh file with the modified data.

Comment: Note: you can open two files on the same line

Comment: @cricket_007 I know that but it complicates the code and OP is a beginner. It is easier to teach a beginner to use `with` one file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear why you even need a file

If you literally meant "remove first characters in a string" and **not** each line of a file, then just strip the message string

```
 x = 10 # some number 
msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
if len(msg) < 2:
  print "Exit"
  break
msg = msg.replace('\n','').replace(' ','')[x:] 
print(msg)
```

If you do want to write the string to a file, then you only need to open it once, after editing your message